# Install dependencies for Python ffmpeg library "av" (ImportError: libx264.so missing)

Tags: python, ffmpeg, dependencies

In Python I installed the library `av` (which is a Python API for ffmpeg) into my conda environment with `conda install -c conda-forge av=0.4.0`, but I when I `import av` into my python script, I get the error message

```
ImportError: libx264.so.138: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

on my Linux Kubuntu 14.4 machine. How can I resolve this issue?

Wild guess: My Kubuntu repositories are a little old, so I cannot update ffmepg further and I guess this is why libx264 is missing, but am not sure.

Comment: Try `apt-get install libx264-dev`. If not works, build and install from source.

Comment: @halfelf: "libx264-dev is  the newest version" How do I build and install from source?

Comment: So what is the "newest version" of your libx264 installation? Does it match "libx264.so.138"?  And check your `av` lib's dependency and rpath, where it looks for `libx264.so`.

Comment: @halfelf: I have installed "libx264-dev", version "3:0.148.2795+gitaaa9aa8-1~trusty", "libx264-142", version "3:0.148.2491+git24e4fed-1~trusty", and "libx264-148", version "3:0.148.2795+gitaaa9aa8-1~trusty". I do not know whether it matches "libx264.so.138".

Comment: Find your `av` lib under python installation, use `ldd` to check its dependencies. `libx264.so.xxx` is usually in `/usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu` in a typical 64bit ubuntu. The dependency filename must match the lib file name to work.

Comment: @halfelf: I do not know how to use ldd to check this. Can you detail how I have to proceed? I guess I am doing this in my bash? But how does the command look like exactly?